# How to use Python to parse a SVG document from URL (get points of a polyline)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, svg

I'm looking for a Python extension to parse a SVG's "points" values from the `<polyline>` elements and print them? Possibly to parse it from the URL? or I could save the SVG and do it locally.

I just need it to parse the `points` values and print them separately for each `polyline` element. So it will print something like this for each `points` value of the current `<polyline>` element.

```
[[239,274],[239,274],[239,274],[239,275],[239,275],[238,276],[238,276],[237,276],[237,276],[236,276],[236,276],[236,277] [236,277],[235,277],[235,277],[234,278],[234,278],[233,279],[233,279],[232,280] [232,280],[231,280],[231,280],[230,280],[230,280],[230,280],[229,280],[229,280]]
```

So after the first `polyline` element gets parsed and printed, it would parse the next `polyline` element and get the value for `points` and print it just like the first one until there is no more to be printed.

The SVG's URL: http://colorillo.com/bx0l.inline.svg

Here is a HTML example of a polyline element from the SVG

```
<polyline points="239,274 239,274 239,274 239,275 239,275 238,276 238,276 237,276 237,276 236,276 236,276 236,277 236,277 235,277 235,277 234,278 234,278 233,279 233,279 232,280 232,280 231,280 231,280 230,280 230,280 230,280 229,280 229,280" style="fill: none; stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-antialiasing: false; stroke-antialias: 0; opacity: 0.8"/>
```

I'm just looking for some quick help, and a example.. If you're able to help me out that would be neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import namedtuple
import requests
import re

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

all_points = []
r = requests.get('http://colorillo.com/bx0l.inline.svg')
if r.status_code == 200:
    data = re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', r.content.decode('utf-8'), count=1)
    root = ET.fromstring(data)
    poly_lines = root.findall('.//polyline')
    for poly_line in poly_lines:
        tmp = []
        _points = poly_line.attrib['points'].split(' ')
        for _p in _points:
            tmp.append(Point(*[int(z) for z in _p.split(',')]))
        all_points.append(tmp)

for points in all_points:
    tmp = [str([p.x, p.y]).replace(' ','') for p in points]
    line = ','.join(tmp)
    print('[' + line + ']')
```

Comment: @Ecks What is wrong with this `[210, 240], [123, 424]` Vs `[210, 240],[123, 424]` - the space between the points?

Comment: @Ecks code was updated. Give it a try. Output looks like: `[[95,394],[96,394],[96,394],[99,394],...`

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is an HTML extraction package somewhere, but this is the kind of task I would do with core python, and the regular expressions module. Let `txt` be the text you presented `<polyline...`, so:

Importing regular expression module

```
In [22]: import re
```

Performing the search:

```
In [24]: g = re.search('polyline points="(.*?)"', txt)
```

In the above regex I use `polyline points="` as an anchor (I omitted the `<` because it has a meaning in regex`) and capture all the rest until the next quotation marks.

The text you want is achieved by:

```
In [25]: g.group(1)
Out[25]: '239,274 239,274 239,274 239,275 239,275 238,276 238,276 237,276 237,276 236,276 236,276 236,277 236,277 235,277 235,277 234,278 234,278 233,279 233,279 232,280 232,280 231,280 231,280 230,280 230,280 230,280 229,280 229,280'
```

### Update

It's safer to use xml to parse the data, here is one way to do it (xml.etree is included with the standard library):

```
In [32]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
In [33]: root = ET.fromstring(txt)
```

Since your data is formatted as a root tag already, you don't need futher extractions:

```
In [35]: root.tag
Out[35]: 'polyline'
```

And all the properties are actually XML attributes, converted to a dictionary:

```
In [37]: root.attrib
Out[37]:
{'points': '239,274 239,274 239,274 239,275 239,275 238,276 238,276 237,276 237,276 236,276 236,276 236,277 236,277 235,277 235,277 234,278 234,278 233,279 233,279 232,280 232,280 231,280 231,280 230,280 230,280 230,280 229,280 229,280', 'style': 'fill: none; stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-antialiasing: false; stroke-antialias: 0; opacity: 0.8'}
```

So here you have it:

```
In [38]: root.attrib['points']
Out[38]: '239,274 239,274 239,274 239,275 239,275 238,276 238,276 237,276 237,276 236,276 236,276 236,277 236,277 235,277 235,277 234,278 234,278 233,279 233,279 232,280 232,280 231,280 231,280 230,280 230,280 230,280 229,280 229,280'
```

If you like further to split this to groups according to commas and spaces, I would do this:

Get all groups separated by a space using `split` with no arguments:

```
>>> p = g.group(1).split()
>>> p
['239,274', '239,274', '239,274', '239,275', '239,275', '238,276', '238,276', '237,276', '237,276', '236,276', '236,276', '236,277', '236,277', '235,277', '235,277', '234,278', '234,278', '233,279', '233,279', '232,280', '232,280', '231,280', '231,280', '230,280', '230,280', '230,280', '229,280', '229,280']
```

Now for each string, split it at the comma  which will return a list of strings. I use `map` to convert each such list to a list of `int`s:

```
>>> p2 = [list(map(int, numbers.split(','))) for numbers in p]
>>> p2
[[239, 274], [239, 274], [239, 274], [239, 275], [239, 275], [238, 276], [238, 276], [237, 276], [237, 276], [236, 276], [236, 276], [236, 277], [236, 277], [235, 277], [235, 277], [234, 278], [234, 278], [233, 279], [233, 279], [232, 280], [232, 280], [231, 280], [231, 280], [230, 280], [230, 280], [230, 280], [229, 280], [229, 280]]
```

And this will shed some more light:

```
>>> '123,456'.split(',')
['123', '456']
>>> list(map(int, '123,456'.split(',')))
[123, 456]
```

Comment: do NOT use regexps to parse XML.

Comment: @IsraelUnterman well edit your answer to use a proper XML parser and I'll happily upvote it.